# Does Git LFS support local or "near" secondary storage/cache?

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-annex

I'd like to know if it's possible to *minimize* the download times of large files when using Git LFS.

specifically, the following scenarios:

- keep files when switching branches
- allow to get files from a different repository in the same network - (which would be faster than accessing the remote "master" server)

[I know git annex has better support for these features, but it's Windows support is problematic.]

Answer (score 13):

To the best of my knowledge Git LFS does keep files when switching branches - its checksum based and holds all blobs locally [under](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/f56cd54ad7f8e13df6415a568f5681394bd44b31/lfs/lfs.go#L99-L119) .git/lfs/objects once it retrieved them once.

As for pointing lfs to a different endpoint - that's already supported: in your `.git/config` you can modify the lfs url it points to:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://...<repo_url>
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
lfsurl = "https://<another repo that's closer to you>"
```

Also there are several [services](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/wiki/Implementations) that provide lfs support so you can keep the storage on your local corp network like [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Git+LFS+Repositories), [GitHub Enterprise](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.5/admin/articles/configuring-git-large-file-storage-for-a-repository/) and [Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/git-large-file-storage-lfs-794364846.html), depending on what your usecase is.

You might find this [issue's](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/766) conversation helpful as well.